# Text is not being echoed at all when CSS and file_get_contents are being used

Tags: php, css, echo, title

```
<html>
<?php
$url = "http://www.youtube.com/embed/FTGNAupPqpU";
$str = "title of video here";
$css = <<<EOT
<style type="text/css">
 body
   {
   background: #eeeeee;
   width:560px; 
   height:315px;
   }
</style>
EOT;
$data = file_get_contents($url);
$data = str_replace('</body>', $css.'</body>', $data);
echo '<div style="overflow:scroll;">'.$data.'</div>';
echo $str
?>
</html>
```

When `$url` has a variable stored in it (mainly being a YouTube video) it does not echo `$str` at all but when `$url` is nothing then `$str` echo's and I don't know why? I would like the video to appear at the top and use `$str` as the title for the video.

Comment: Its working http://codepad.viper-7.com/b3DW9K

Comment: can you see the contents of `$data` in data is being returned ?

Comment: issue is not with ur data or code .. problem is your video is covering your string.. need to set css mainly

Comment: Opps !! someone answered it before me .. anyways glad your problem is solved :)

Comment: You already marked an answer as accepted - there is no need to edit your question title to reflect that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your video container and body height were equal so all the content after that div were hidden
See if this works:

```
<html>
<?php
$url = "http://www.youtube.com/embed/FTGNAupPqpU";
$str = "title of video here";
$css = <<<EOT
<style type="text/css">
 body
   {
   background: #eeeeee;
   width:560px; 
   height:315px;
   color:#000;
   }
</style>
EOT;
$data = file_get_contents($url);
$data = str_replace('</body>', $css.'</body>', $data);
echo '<div style="overflow:scroll; height:300px;">'.$data.'</div>';
echo $str;
?>
</html>
```

Comment: @edd Yes thank you it worked!!! Im so happy now :D. And also a big thanks to anyone else that responded to my question you where so nice with your responces!

Answer (score 0):

Try this ..
You need to control the height and width of div in which you are showing the data

```
<html>
<?php
$url = "http://www.youtube.com/embed/FTGNAupPqpU";
$str = "title of video here";
$css = <<<EOT
<style type="text/css">
 body
 {
  background: #fff;
    width:560px; 
  height:315px;
  }
</style>
EOT;
$data = file_get_contents($url);
echo '<div style="overflow:scroll; height:500px;width:500px">'.$data.'</div>';
echo $str
?>
</html>
```

see [phpfiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/95g-qdk)